# Need to remove dropdown options after flag changed

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am using select in angularJS also used group by to show it in group. I am using flag which comes from a database, if flag is false i want to hide some options, else if true want to show the options. My flag takes some time to come before that select is get rendered hence option is not getting hide. how to remove those options after i get my flag from database.

```
<select class="form-control margin-bottom-20" ng-model="tempfilter"
        ng-change="tempFilterChange()"
        ng-options="color.name group by color.shade for color in colorOptions | 
                    filter:notAnOption=true">
     <option value="" selected="selected">View All</option>
</select>
```

In .JS

```
$scope.filterOptions = [           
     { value: "1", name: 'black', shade: 'dark', notAnOption: $scope.isWall },
     { value: "2", name: 'red', shade: 'dark', notAnOption: $scope.isWall },
     { value: "3", name: 'green', shade: 'not dark', notAnOption: $scope.isWall },
     { value: "4", name: 'yellow', shade: 'not dark', notAnOption: true },
     { value: "1", name: 'blue', shade: 'not dark', notAnOption: true }
 ];
```

Answer (score 1):

The controller needs to re-compute the filter options whenever the `$scope.isWall` property changes:

```
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  function filterOptions() {
    return [           
     { value: "1", name: 'black', shade: 'dark', notAnOption: $scope.isWall },
     { value: "2", name: 'red', shade: 'dark', notAnOption: $scope.isWall },
     { value: "3", name: 'green', shade: 'not dark', notAnOption: $scope.isWall },
     { value: "4", name: 'yellow', shade: 'not dark', notAnOption: true },
     { value: "1", name: 'blue', shade: 'not dark', notAnOption: true }
    ];
  };
  //INITIALIZE colorOptions
  $scope.colorOptions = filterOptions();
  //UPDATE colorOption
  $scope.wallChange = function() {
    $scope.colorOptions = filterOptions();
    console.log($scope.colorOptions);
  }
})
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/a2gP4lDigIVB75yF0PhK?p=preview)

Comment: It works as i called same but in $watch function when flag gets changed i call the same but some values are always true as i showed in code. If value from that filter is selected then it must shown selected after filter values are re-rendered can we show that? and how?

Answer (score 0):

in filter of ng-options you can call a function that return a boolean result.

try in this way

```
    <select class="form-control margin-bottom-20" ng-model="tempfilter"
            ng-change="tempFilterChange()"
ng-options="color.name group by color.shade for color in filterOptions | filter:isNotAnOption">
         <option value="" selected="selected">View All</option>
    </select>



$scope.filterOptions = [           
     { value: "1", name: 'black', shade: 'dark', notAnOption: $scope.isWall },
     { value: "2", name: 'red', shade: 'dark', notAnOption: $scope.isWall },
     { value: "3", name: 'green', shade: 'not dark', notAnOption: $scope.isWall },
     { value: "4", name: 'yellow', shade: 'not dark', notAnOption: true },
     { value: "1", name: 'blue', shade: 'not dark', notAnOption: true }
 ];


$scope.isNotAnOption = function(element){
return element.notAnOption && element.notAnOption === true;
}
```

Comment: though i call function it wont get call again when i received my flag  $scope.isWall again from a database.

Comment: how do you get from database? do you update $scope ?

Comment: yes i update $scope.isWall variable which is a flag i get from database. If we change the settings flag changes from true or false. So when i hit search button i fetch this flag again and want to re-render this dropdown. Now i have done this through $watch function, by doing this i can able to bind values but selected value doesn't appear how can i set selected value to dropdown.